# Custom Post Types with Parent Pages - best practice

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am working on a site with product categories and individual products organized like this:

product category 1

- product
- product
- product

product category 2

- product

etc...

It was suggested to me that the best way to do organize the individual products was to create a custom post type for products. The product categories are currently pages.

So now I am trying to figure out the best way to connect a product custom post type with its particular product category page (so that url structure can be "/product_category/product/").

I am sure there is a smart and efficient way to do this, but I'm not seeing it. I was thinking that I could add categories to the pages and CPT's - but that isn't quite the effect that I want because I don't want them to only be accessible as archive pages. Is that actually a problem?

Sorry that this is such a broad question - I can get it to work but am sure that my first try would not be the best way, so I am just looking for some pointers or examples from people who have done this before to steer me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I did get this right. Part of my problem was due to a misunderstanding about how to use categories in wordpress.

What I ended up doing was use the custom taxonomy as shown by Austin Winstanely's answer, and then refactor my page organization a little bit so that the product category was not a page post type, but a category - displayed using the category template. This makes it very convenient, because individual products in the custom post type can be associated with their product category very easily. When I asked the question I had not understood that categories could have their own template and function as web pages.

Thanks for the help! 
-Alyssa

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Custom Taxonomies](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy).

```
function product_categories_init() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'product-category',
        'product', // Or 'post', whatever the custom post type is
        array(
            'label'              => __( 'Product Categories' ),
            'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'product-categories' ),
            'hierarchical'       => false,
            'show_ui'            => true,
            'show_admin_column'  => true,
            'query_var'          => true,
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'product_categories_init' );
```

This is a simple example. You'll have to check out the options in the reference link. But it is essentially your own kind of category for a post type (or an array of post types).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer - that makes perfect sense. I am still running into trouble getting the relationship between products and product groups to do what I need it to however, and am considering just creating separate pages for the products instead of using CPT's, but maybe I am not understanding something. Do you see reasons why it is necessary or beneficial to use CPT's in this case?

Comment: It's really kind of a preference. You could certainly do individual custom post types for each type of product (if they are different enough to need to, like t-shirts vs digital downloads or something) and then create shortcodes to query the different types and add them to the pages. Custom Taxonomies is just a bit more organized. What's the trouble you're having with getting it to do what you need? In other words, what is it you need to do? I understand you essentially want categories but not with the standard post categories, right?

Comment: Have you looked at WooCommerce? Even if you don't want to use it, I would suggest setting up a dummy site and installing WooCommerce just to look through the code to see how they do it. It's just good to see someone else's code as an example.